# Typescript: conditional type depending on whether type is undefined

Tags: typescript, conditional-types, typescript-conditional-types

I am creating a series of class which all extend an abstract class `Operation<T, R>`, on which is defined the method `perform(t: T): R`.

I want a conditional operation `ConditionalOperation<T, R> extends Operation<T, T | R>`, with a constructor which signature would be similar to this one:

```js
constructor(
    private predicate: (value: T) => boolean,
    private thenOp: Operation<T, R>,
    private elseOp?: Operation<T, R>
) {
    super();
}
```

The method `perform` of this operation would work as follows:

- If `elseOp` is defined, the input value is passed to `thenOp` if the predicate is true, else it is passed to `elseOp`.
- If `elseOp` is undefined, the input value is passed to `thenOp` if the predicate is true, else the value is returned directly.

This behaviour is the reason for the `T | R` in the signature of `ConditionalOperation`: if the `elseOp` is defined, the return type is `R`, otherwise it's `T | R`.

Now, I would like to try and see if there is a way to typecheck the `ConditionalOperation` to have a return type that depends on whether `elseOp` is defined. I tried the following:

```js
abstract class Operation<T, R> {
  abstract perform(t: T): R;
}

type ConditionalReturnType<T, R, EOp extends Operation<T, R>> = undefined extends EOp ? T | R : R;

class ConditionalOperation<T, R, EOp extends Operation<T, R>> extends Operation<T, ConditionalReturnType<T, R, EOp>> {
  constructor(
        private predicate: (value: T) => boolean,
        private thenOp: Operation<T, R>,
        private elseOp?: EOp
    ) {
        super();
    }

  perform(t: T): ConditionalReturnType<T, R, EOp> {
    if (this.predicate(t)) {
      return this.thenOp.perform(t);
    } else if (typeof this.elseOp !== 'undefined') {
      return this.elseOp.perform(t);
    } else {
      return t; // Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ConditionalReturnType<T, R, EOp>'.
    }
  }
}
```

Typescript does not seem to allow returning `t` here, even though we know at this point that `elseOp` is undefined, which should be possible if and only if `ConditionalReturnType<T, R, EOp>` is `T | R`.

Is there another way of doing this, aside from creating two conditional classes?

Comment: So TS currently cannot use control flow analysis to affect type parameters, so it is nearly impossible to return a value of a generic conditional type and have the compiler verify it as safe.  This is a missing feature described at [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912).  For now the most convenient approach is to just use a type assertion and move on, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/N9YX3N).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer (or find a suitable dupe target). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: This does address the question, thanks! Subsequent question, more about style this time: you assert with `any`, wouldn't it be clearer to assert with `ConditionalReturnType<T, R, EOp>` in your opinion?

Comment: It would be clearer, but uses more keystrokes. It's up to you.  Followup questions don't really belong in comments, so if you have more questions after the question post as asked above is resolved, you might want to open a new post for it.

Comment: Got it, thanks! My thought process was that it did not warrant an additional question because it was related to something you said in your comment.